# create select box dynamically with textbox's value number of types

Tags: jquery, select

I wanted to create a select box dynamically but with text box's value number of times. If user insert 100 then select box with 100 option should be created dynamically.
Here's my code, how I did it.

---

```
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt">
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var num;
$("#txt").blur(function(){
        num = $('#txt').val();
        num = parseInt(num);
        alert('created');
        var arr = [];
        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) { 
               var pusssh =  {val : i, text: i+'_text'}
               arr.push(pusssh);
               }
        var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
        $(arr).each(function() {
         sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="txt">
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#txt").change(function(){
        if ($("#idselect"))
             $("#idselect").remove();
        var num = $(this).val();
        var st = '';
        for (i=1; i<=num; i++)
            st += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
        $(this).append('<select id="idselect">' + st + '</select>');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple in jquery(**Don't forget to add Jquery Reference**) You can do it as below:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<select id="myddl">

</select>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$("#myInput").change(function(){
var val=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
AddOptions(val)
})
function AddOptions(val)
{
     $('#myddl').empty();
    for(i=1;i<=val;i++)
    {
        var newOption = $('<option>');
        newOption.attr('value', i).text('Lavel'+i);
        $('#myddl').append(newOption);
    }
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dFK3K/508/)**

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you want to update your `<select>` if someone changes the value in the input (in stead of making another `<select>`). Here's your updated code:

```js
$("#txt").blur(function() {
var num = $('#txt').val();
num = parseInt(num);
console.log('Creating a select with ' + num + ' options...')
var arr = [];
for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  var pusssh = {
    val: i,
    text: i + '_text'
  }
  arr.push(pusssh);
}
if($('#sel').length == 0) {
  var sel = $('<select id="sel">').appendTo('body');
}
$('#sel').find('option').remove();
$(arr).each(function() {
  $('#sel').append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```